# HTML 5 drag and drop in firefox not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, file, firefox, drag-and-drop

I am implementing a file processor in JS and HTML 5 and it is working as expected in Chome, but not in Firefox.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vapocalypse/G9QbX/

In Firefox, the drop event is forwarded to the browser, which opens the file, not being processed by my script. It behaves as if I dropped something over an empty tab.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried changing from jQuery to native DOM using getElementById and overriding the ondrop method, but same results...

Thanks,
Apoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your basic problem is that you're not cancelling the `dragover` event on the the element you're trying to capture the `drop` event on.  The `drop` event is ignored in this case.  Here is the code I added:

```
$('#topDiv').bind("dragenter dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I also removed the `$(document).ready` form your code and just set the jsFiddle to run all the JS onDomReady instead, but I don't think that made much difference.  [Here's the example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/G9QbX/76/).

Comment: By the way, how did you figure it was that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, see http://jsfiddle.net/G9QbX/75/. It's based on your's example. Don't know why, but dragover event is not boud via $.bind or addEventListener functions in FF14. The example is very dirty, but it works. I will write if i find a better solution.

Comment: As @robertc pointed out, it was the `dragover` event not being cancelled, and is what you did too. Thanks!